# powershell json DateFormat

Tags: json, api, powershell, date, intune

returned data from rest-API as JSON where the data/time is formated as

```
{
  "userKey":  ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤,
  "userId":  "¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤",
  "userEmail":  "¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤",
  "userPrincipalName":  "¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤",
  "displayName":  "¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤",
  "intuneLicensed":  true,
  "isDeleted":  true,
  "startDateInclusiveUTC":  "2017-10-16T00:00:00Z",
  "endDateExclusiveUTC":  "9999-12-31T00:00:00Z",
  "isCurrent":  true,
  "rowLastModifiedDateTimeUTC":  "2017-10-17T00:24:11.8233333Z",
  "PictureUrl":  "¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤.dk"
}
```

date/time is not formated properly, the data is from Intune DataWareHouse API

the data is requested via PowerShell my Question is it a PowerShell Shell Bug or this how JSON handel Data Formats

The Date Shold Appear as
MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS

[see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBOTZ.png)

Comment: Looks like perfectly valid ISO-8601 to me. JSON doesn't have any native way of describing dates and times. The prevailing ways of handling this is either a string containing a serialized description of the date as you see, or a number, which is usually in Unix-time (i.e. UTC seconds since 1970-01-01). In terms of readability, precision and flexibility, the string version usually is a clear winner.

Comment: If you need to change this format you'll have do so after receiving the data.  This is the format in which the server is sending.

Answer (score 1):

The date is simply a string containing the date as ISO-8601 (because JSON doesn't have a DateTime type). Parse the date, and then format it as a different string:

```
PS> [datetime]::parse("9999-12-31T00:00:00Z").Tostring('MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss')
12-31-99 01:00:00
```

Comment: i took a look at the  wiki about ISO-8610 ,

Answer (score 0):

i did a Convertfrom-json and then looping through every Note Property, if there is a better approach feel free to comment :)

```
$IntuneCollectionData | get-member -type NoteProperty | foreach-object {
    if ($_.value -match "(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d+)|(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)|(\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d)")
    {

        $NewDateTime = [datetime]::parse("$($_.value)").Tostring('MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss')

        $_.value = $NewDateTime 

    }

}
```